# What happens to Windows 10 Dev Environment after 90 days?

Tags: windows, license

I'm first time using Windows 10 Dev Environment (running on Hyper-V) and I saw that I only have 90 days of usage with this image. It's been 2 days and I've setup most of the tools that I will need for further work. Do I have to download and setup another image every 90 days or I can continue to use this one after this period expires?

Answer (score 9):

After 90 days the VM will not be usable any more, and this is done on purpose.
You will lose all your programs that you have setup.

You will need a fresh VM image and repeat your setup of it every 90 days.
You don't need to download it again if you take a VM snapshot before starting it
for the first time (afterwards it's too late).

If you wish your setup to last more than 90 days, you need to buy a Windows
serial key from Microsoft or a vendor.
Note that you can't use this serial to activate the evaluation VM, so you'll need
to create a new VM from scratch, activate it and repeat your setup.

Comment: Is it still true that there is no way to activate an expired Windows 10 development VM?. I see something different in https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-visual-studio/new-developer-vms-microsoft-can-now-be-fully-licensed.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel: That article details VMs that are not activated at all, but need to be activated with a key.

Comment: You can add HDD to you Hyper-V installation (Settings... ->Hardware -> SCSI Controller -> Hard Drive -> Add) and keep all your files there, after you renew image add existing HDD to you new machine. At least you will keep your files but still you need to install your programs or use portable versions instead

Answer (score -1):

For anyone curious about the current policy with *Windows 11* dev environments, the MS web page says "If the evaluation period expires, the desktop background will turn black, you will see a persistent desktop notification indicating that the system is not genuine, and the PC will shut down every hour." This sounds much less awful than the accepted answer for Win 10 (not usable at all).

(The web page in question is https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/)

I'm unsure if there's any way to tell how many days are left before expiry, other than just making a note when downloading the original image.